# Stuck trying change mysql root password

Tags: mysql

I have looked up how to change the root password online and they always tell me to do `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` When i run that it doesn't do anything except from outputting this:

```
matthew@matthewserver:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 24648
matthew@matthewserver:~$ 2018-10-03T20:44:58.008288Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2018-10-03T20:44:58.013391Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-10-03T20:44:58.041802Z mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

I have defiantly started mysql. I can however do sudo mysql. when i did sudo mysql i ran this `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '******';` but when i tried logging in it just outputted:

```
matthew@matthewserver:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Answer (score 1):

The message

> A mysqld process already exists

is clear:  You need to stop MySQL before running this, as MySQL can never run more than once on the same system.  How this is done depends on your environment, about which you tell us nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To change the mysql root password, I would suggest to follow the bellow procedure :

1 - Stop you mysqld instance

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

2 - Start MySQL without a password

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

3 - Connect as root and change his password

```
mysql -uroot
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

4 - Restart your mysqld instance

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Comment: i couldn't stop mysqld, did you mean mysql because i can do sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

Comment: This is really depend on your operating system. I'm using centos / redhat most of the times and mysql is call mysqld. If you are using a debian based it should be `/etc/init.d/mysql`

Comment: Alternately you could use `service mysql start | stop | restart`

Comment: when i run the second step i get an empty line and then when i run the third step it says: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)